# Custom /etc/hosts file in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, composer-php, hosts

I am working on a project where /etc/hosts file with an additional entry must exist during container build, however the problems are as follows:

1. During the build there is no hosts file at all.
2. During the build everything is in read-only mode and I can't create the hosts file.
3. In docker I even mounted an existing hosts file, but when I build, ITS STILL DOESNT EXISTS!

Everywhere written about extra_hosts, but these entries are added when the container is upped, they are not present during the build.

What is the solution to this problem? I need /etc/hosts existence.

[image: Dockerfile]

It used to work like this, but on my machine this line of the dockerfile returns an "read-only" error.

Docker Compose version 2.11.2, Docker version 20.10.18

Comment: You can specify `extra_hosts` in your docker compose file

Comment: @NaphatAmundsen yup, I've tried.  But during container build there is no hosts file with extra hosts. And it is the main problem.

Comment: Why do you need to modify `/etc/hosts` at all; can you fix this (maybe by correctly configuring DNS in your environment)?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:composer-php]? Is this really related to Composer? Also, please share all text content in text form, not hidden in a screenshot

Comment: @NicoHaase maybe something like hosts exist in composer. This host is Toran for composer and using only for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze it is not my own project, but project of company where I work, and guys from there don't understand what is wrong (they are don't have problem like this). I can't fix it, because this architecture error (like composer install in dockerfiles) is a really long story for fix (tests, builds, deploys ...) . So, I can't work because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra host during build:

```
docker build --help | grep host
      --add-host list           Add a custom host-to-IP mapping (host:ip)
```

This will create `/etc/hosts` and add the entries you need.

Docker-compose also supports this as of schema version 3.9. You can see the ful documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#extra_hosts).

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      extra_hosts:
      - "somehost:162.242.195.82"
      - "otherhost:50.31.209.229"
```

Comment: I did not notice that extra_hosts can be entered in the build tab. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It’s a new feature in 3.9. You need to dig deep in the documentation to find it :) that’s why I added the link.